# How is each_with_object supposed to work?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how `each_with_object` is supposed to be used.

I have a sum example that doesn't work:

```
> (1..3).each_with_object(0) {|i,sum| sum+=i}
=> 0
```

I would assume that the result would be 6 ! Where is my mistake ?

Comment: By the way. Can someone tell me why Ruby is not throwing some kind of error when doing `sum+=i`, ie. trying to modify an immutable object ? The whole point here is that the poor user is left alone with no clue that his command is just silently failing...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`each_with_object` does not work on immutable objects like integer.

```
(1..3).each_with_object(0) {|i,sum| sum += i} #=> 0
```

This is because `each_with_object` iterates over a collection, passing each element and the given object to the block. It does not update the value of object after each iteration and returns the original given object.

It would work with a hash since changing value of a hash key changes it for original object by itself.

```
(1..3).each_with_object({:sum => 0}) {|i,hsh| hsh[:sum] += i}
#=> {:sum => 6}
```

`String` objects are interesting case. They are mutable so you might expect the following 
to return "abc"

```
("a".."c").each_with_object("") {|i,str| str += i} # => ""
```

but it does not. This is because `str += "a"` returns a new object and the original object stays the same. However if we do

```
("a".."c").each_with_object("") {|i,str| str << i} # => "abc"
```

it works because `str << "a"` modifies the original object.

For more info see ruby docs for [each_with_object](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)

For your purpose, use [inject](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject)

```
(1..3).inject(0) {|sum,i| sum += i} #=> 6
# or
(1..3).inject(:+) #=> 6
```

Comment: Well, thanks. Indeed, I was reading the doc here : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object and there is no mention of such detail. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `sum+=i` is `sum = sum + i` and `sum = ...` won't change the `sum` that was passed in, it will just assign a new value to a local variable. `inject` works because `inject` feeds the block's return value back into the next iteration, you'd probably be better off writing `(1..3).inject(0) {|sum,i| sum + i }` or even `(1..3).inject(:+)` in this case, `sum += i` inside the `inject` block is misleading and confusing.

Comment: I would prefer `sum+i` as it more clear,  but `each_with_object` will not work with that. I wanted show that the code OP had works with `inject` but not with `each_with_object`

Comment: But the whole approach won't work with `each_with_object` since `Fixnum`s are, as you've noted, immutable. `each_with_object` is simply the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: This is a great solution and these examples should be added to ruby docs!

Answer (score 15):

A simple, but common example of using `each_with_object` is when you need to build a hash depending on elements in an array. Very often you see something like:

```
hash = {}
[1, 2, 3, 4].each { |number| hash[number] = number**2 }
hash
```

Using `each_with_object` avoids the explicit initialization and return of the `hash` variable.

```
[1,2,3,4].each_with_object({}) { |number, hash| hash[number] = number**2 }
```

I advise reading the docs for `inject`, `tap`, and `each_with_index`. These methods are helpful when you aim for short and readable code.

Answer (score 10):

The documentation of [***`Enumerable#each_with_object`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is very clear :

> Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object given, and ***returns the initially given object***.

In your case, `(1..3).each_with_object(0) {|i,sum| sum+=i}`,you are passing `0`,which is immutable object. Thus here the intial object to `each_with_object` method is `0`,so method returns `0`.It works at it is advertised. See below how `each_with_object` works ,

```
(1..3).each_with_object(0) do |e,mem|
    p "#{mem} and #{e} before change"
    mem = mem + e
    p mem
end

# >> "0 and 1 before change"
# >> 1
# >> "0 and 2 before change"
# >> 2
# >> "0 and 3 before change"
# >> 3
```

That means in every pass,`mem` is set to *initial passed object*. You might be thinking of the in first pass `mem` is `0`,then in next pass `mem` is the result of `mem+=e`,i.e. `mem` will be `1`.But NO,in every pass `mem` is your initial object,which is `0`.

Comment: Ok, I just learned that integer were immutable, which I wasn't aware of. Thanks.