# How can I chain with_index and with_object on an enumerable in ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, ruby-block

I want to process the array `['a', 'b', 'c']` to return the string `'0a1b2c'` (i.e, string formed by concatenating each index with its value).

I can do this:

```
result = ''
['a', 'b', 'c'].each.with_index do |char, i|
  result += "#{i}#{char}"
end  
result
```

I want to eliminate the result variable outside the block by using with_object.

Something like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each.with_index.with_object('') do |char, i, result|
  result += "#{i}#{char}"
end
```

But this raises an error `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Try this: `enum = ['a', 'b', 'c'].each.with_index.with_object('') #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["a", "b", "c"]:each>:with_index>:with_object("")>`. The elements generated by this enumerator and passed to the block will be `enum.to_a #=> [[["a", 0], ""], [["b", 1], ""], [["c", 2], ""]]` This tells you how the block variables need to be written: `(char, i), result = enum.next #=> [["a", 0], ""]`, so `char #=> "a"; i #=> 0; result #=> ""`. Note `result` will change in the course of the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
arr.each.with_index.with_object('') { |(each, n), obj| ... }
```

How does this work?

- Applying both `with_index` and `with_object` creates nested tuples
- `(each, n), obj` unpacks both tuples

---

Fun fact—or maybe rather sad fact—the nested tuple actually materialized as a short-lived array so this will create `O(n)` arrays. If this is a critical production codepath I would away nesting these two enumeration functions. Since you most likely are going to assign `obj` to a variable in the outer scope anyway it would make most sense to rewrite this as

```
obj = ''
arr.each_with_index { |each, n| ... }
```

Comment: Actually, they should not be nested. Updated with performance discussion.

Comment: What does `Benchmark` say? Sometimes things in Ruby are counter-intuitively fast.

Comment: Short-lived objects are a common main performance issue in Ruby applications, it is hard to measure this with `benchmark` though since the cost of object creation occurs in garbage collection.

Comment: It's not hard to measure it, you just need to run it for more than a trivial number of cycles. General rule of thumb is if you're not getting 10s-60s runs for each of your iterations you're not doing enough cycles to collect meaningful data. You're right that the garbage collector can be the biggest price to pay, which is why you really have to lay into it when testing.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't use the methods you ask for, but it does the job and is relatively compact :

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
(0...array.size).zip(array).join
#=> "0a1b2c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both operations should be done without abusing `each` iterator:

```
%w|a b c|.map.with_index do |char, i|
  "#{i}#{char}"
end.join

%w|a b c|.each_with_object('').with_index do |(char, result), i|
  result << "#{i}#{char}"
end
```

Or, if you still want to use each:

```
%w|a b c|.each.with_index.with_object('') do |char_idx, result|
  result << char_idx.join
end
```

Comment: `map.with_index` is really nice!

Answer (score 0):

Something important about this solution, which is nice :

```rb
%w|a b c|.each_with_object('').with_index do |(char, result), i|
  result << "#{i}#{char}"
end
```

Here we use `<<` instead of `+=`.

`with_object` only works with mutable objects, and you might think that string is mutable, so why wouldn't we be able to use `+=`? Because `+=` is equivalent to `x = x+y`, so it generates a new object each time.

In the end, if you use `+=` with `with_object`, you never mutate the original object you created, you just create a new object you won't keep track of in the block at each iteration.

More details here: [How is each_with_object supposed to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064209/how-is-each-with-object-supposed-to-work)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please have a look at [how to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (specifically in regards to code formatting) to improve the readability of future posts.

Comment: Done & absolutely sorry about that!