# Not able to create an ('A'..'Z') initialised hash in ruby class? Why?

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, hash

I want to create a hash, that is initialised with the letters `'A'..'Z'` and `""` on the other hand.

```
abcliste = {}
('A'..'Z').to_a.each { |letter| abcliste[letter] = ""}
print abcliste # => {"A"=>"", "B"=>"", "C"=>"", ... , "Z"=>""}
```

**But**, if I use a class, with the same code, I will get an array `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", ... , "Z"]`:

```
class Abcliste
  def initialize
    @abcliste = {}
    @abcliste = ('A'..'Z').to_a.each { |letter| @abcliste.store(letter, "") }
    print @abcliste # => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", ... , "Z"]
  end
end

a = Abcliste.new # => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", ... , "Z"]
```

1. Why is this so?
2. How can I write a class, so that I generates an hash from ('A'..'Z')

Comment: " if I use a class, with the **same code**" – Here's a hint: it's not the same code. Compare the differences, and you will find the error.

Answer (score 2):

## Your code

You don't need `to_a`, and you shouldn't overwrite @abcliste :

```
@abcliste = {}
('A'..'Z').each{ |letter| @abcliste.store(letter,"")}
print @abcliste
```

## Alternatives

#### each_with_object

The above code can be shortened with `each_with_object` :

```
@abcliste = ('A'..'Z').each_with_object({}) { |letter, liste| liste.store(letter,"") }
```

#### map

```
('A'..'Z').map{|letter| [letter, ""] }.to_h
#=> {"A"=>"", "B"=>"", "C"=>"", "D"=>"", "E"=>"", "F"=>"", "G"=>"", "H"=>"", "I"=>"", "J"=>"", "K"=>"", "L"=>"", "M"=>"", "N"=>"", "O"=>"", "P"=>"", "Q"=>"", "R"=>"", "S"=>"", "T"=>"", "U"=>"", "V"=>"", "W"=>"", "X"=>"", "Y"=>"", "Z"=>""}
```

It first creates an array of pairs (letter and ""), and converts it to a Hash.

#### hash with default

Yet another possibility would be to just define a Hash with a default value :

```
@abcliste = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = "" }
p @abcliste
#=> {}
@abcliste["A"] << 'letters'
p @abcliste["A"]
#=> "letters"
p @abcliste["B"]
#=> ""
```

Comment: `('A'..'Z').zip([""]*('A'..'Z').count).to_h`

Comment: @mudasobwa: Thanks. I though about it, but `zip` doesn't make sense here IMHO.

Comment: @mudasobwa beautifully elegant! You can even shorten it to `('a'..'z').zip(['']).to_h`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `#each` will return the array you iterated over. Hence after you assign that to `@abcliste`, all the `#store` calls don't matter as you have replaced the value of the instance variable altogether.

Remove the second assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens in your code

```
@abcliste = {}
@abcliste = ('A'..'Z').to_a.each { |letter| @abcliste[letter] = "" }
```

Things happen in this order

- You create `{}` and assign to `@abcliste`
- You use an `each` loop to store all values in the hash
- `@abcliste` has the correct value now, but then …
- You assign the return value of `each` to `@abcliste` — uh oh!

When you execute `array.each { ... }` the return value of `each` is the array `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
class Abcliste
  def initialize
    @abcliste = {}
    ('A'..'Z').to_a.each { |letter| @abcliste.store(letter, "") }
    print @abcliste
  end
end

a = Abcliste.new
```

output:

```
{"A"=>"", "B"=>"", "C"=>"", "D"=>"", "E"=>"", "F"=>"", "G"=>"", "H"=>"", "I"=>"", "J"=>"", "K"=>"", "L"=>"", "M"=>"", "N"=>"", "O"=>"", "P"=>"", "Q"=>"", "R"=>"", "S"=>"", "T"=>"", "U"=>"", "V"=>"", "W"=>"", "X"=>"", "Y"=>"", "Z"=>""} => #<Abcliste:0x888f9d4 @abcliste={"A"=>"", "B"=>"", "C"=>"", "D"=>"", "E"=>"", "F"=>"", "G"=>"", "H"=>"", "I"=>"", "J"=>"", "K"=>"", "L"=>"", "M"=>"", "N"=>"", "O"=>"", "P"=>"", "Q"=>"", "R"=>"", "S"=>"", "T"=>"", "U"=>"", "V"=>"", "W"=>"", "X"=>"", "Y"=>"", "Z"=>""}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [I think it is bad practice to use object initialization to do more than load data into a newly create instance](http://nicholshayes.co.uk/blog/?p=267). If all you want to do is pass around a function, then you should use a Module and not a Class.

```
module Abcliste
  def self.for(range, content = '')
    range.each_with_object({}){|element, hash| hash[element] = content}
  end
end

puts Abcliste.for 'A'..'Z'
```

Will output:

> {"A"=>"", "B"=>"", "C"=>"", "D"=>"", "E"=>"", "F"=>"", "G"=>"",
>   "H"=>"", "I"=>"", "J"=>"", "K"=>"", "L"=>"", "M"=>"", "N"=>"",
>   "O"=>"", "P"=>"", "Q"=>"", "R"=>"", "S"=>"", "T"=>"", "U"=>"",
>   "V"=>"", "W"=>"", "X"=>"", "Y"=>"", "Z"=>""}

And this code will also allow you to do this:

```
puts Abcliste.for 1..10, 'foo'
```

> {1=>"foo", 2=>"foo", 3=>"foo", 4=>"foo", 5=>"foo", 6=>"foo", 7=>"foo",
>   8=>"foo", 9=>"foo", 10=>"foo"}

Comment: Note: if you need to return `hash` every time in your `inject`, you need `each_with_object`.

Comment: Good point - though you do need to be careful with `each_with_object` http://stackoverflow.com/a/19064234/1014251

Comment: Yes - and I'm just about to update my answer to show that. I just wanted to add a note about the difference between `inject` and `each_with_object`. I should have updated, then commented.